# Find regularly spaced value transitions in sorted column of HDFStore

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

#### Question

I want to make a tool to find value transition boundaries within a sorted column of a Pandas HDFStore.  I want to do this as fast as possible for a broad range of data distributions.

#### Example

Given a large sorted column

```
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 10, 10, 15]
```

I'm going to select a few regularly spaced locations

```
[1, 1, 3, *3*, 3, 3, 3, *5*, 6, 9, 10, *10*, 10, 15]
```

From these I want to move to the right to the next point where there is a transition of values, i.e. where the next value is different from the current value

```
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, *3*, *5*, 6, 9, 10, 10, *10*, 15]
```

I want to do this quickly and robustly, regardless of the distribution of data that I get.

#### Some concerns

- My data may be large and expensive to load from disk.  I don't want to load the entire thing into memory
- Converselly I suspect that loading one element at a time will be very slow, and so I probably want to pull in chunks of 100 rows or something.  What's a good rule of thumb here?
- I may have very many columns.  How do I best avoid unnecessary costs given that I only care about one column (I know that HDFStore is row-oriented, still, there might be something clever here)
- I may run into very long sorted sequences (hundreds of thousands of elements)